# Why isn't autoplay working despite the video being loaded again?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've a webpage which displays random videos on load. These random videos are being stored in an array.

```
function playVideo() {
  const videoEl = $('.video');
  const videoSrc = $('.video source');
  const vid = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
  console.log(vid, videos[vid]);

  videoSrc.attr('src', videos[vid]);
  videoEl[0].autoplay = true;
  // videoEl[0].controls = true;
  videoEl[0].load();
}
```

The src contains the right path and each time different video is added to the page, but the autoplay option doesn't work. I've tried replacing it with play(), creating a new video tag and appending it to the body, but these methods haven't worked either.

Why is the autoplay option being blocked? In Safari, when I click on spacebar for the first time, it plays. Could it be a browser related issue?